# MySQL: Dynamic views based on year value

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my input table:

**Input table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      date           |        total     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12-1-2017        |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12-2-2017        |         20       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12-1-2016        |         30       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12-2-2016        |         40       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    12-3-2016        |         50       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would want the resultant of the query to have dynamic year columns like below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        day          |   total_2017     |   total_2016     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       12-1          |         10       |         30       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       12-2          |         20       |         40       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       12-3          |         0        |         50       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Can anyone help me with the best approach?

Comment: Extract month and day. GROUP BY. Case expressions to do conditional aggregation for each year.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select month(date), day(date),
       sum(case when year(date) = 2017 then total else 0 end) as total_2017,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2016 then total else 0 end) as total_2016
from t
group by month(date), day(date);
```

Comment: Can we update it to pull the year field dynamically?

Comment: @SupreetTotagi . . . Yes.  You can use `year(now())` instead of 2018, for instance.